# Single signon from multiple applications

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net mvc application that I'd like to use forms authentication with two other asp.net apps that don't have the same machine key.  Any thoughts on this?  I don't have control of the machine keys for the other apps and they aren't the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can point your connection string for authentication to a database that all application can access.

So if you have the default database that .NET creates, you can point your other application to that as well for authentication.

If you use the Database Publishing Wizard from MS then you can take the created database and copy that to any SQL database and then point each applications membership provider at that database.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can also delegate you authentication operation to a service and use it from each app.