# ASP.NET: Questions about ASPNETDB.MDF

Tags: asp.net

in my web site i have two databases, ASPNETDB.MDF and a self created one (database.mdf). (The don't contain a lot of data yet)
But i need a relationship (foreign key) between a table in ASPNETDB.MDF and a table in database.mdf.

So i guess i need to merge both databases first, would you just extend the "ASPNETDB.MDF" with the tables from "database.mdf" ?
or better configure "database.mdf" for the asp.net Applicatoin Services and then delete "ASPNETDB.MDF" ?
Is "ASPNETDB.MDF" even meant to be used in a production online web application?

(Right now i'm using sql server express but i will probably use sql server when deploying Site to a shared host)

thanks a lot for answers

Answer (score 0):

the scripts for the structure that is inside ASPNETDB.MDF are deployable on a different database (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx)

however, I would really consider wether or not you want to do a foreign key to those tables, the membership, roles and profile API is intended to be used as a pluggable API, something you will break by defining your foreign key

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if i dont do a foreign key to those tables, how would you implement a relatioship to an logged in user ? for exc. in my site users can write product reviews, so in my reviews table i have a column "UserId" that i wanted to point to the column "UserId"  (table "aspnet_Users" from ASPNETDB.MDF) to implement a relationship...

Comment: I would combine the ProviderName / ProviderUserKey from the MembershipUser class

Answer (score 0):

[Setting up membership in existing database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121741/how-do-i-setup-a-membership-provider-in-my-existing-database-using-asp-net-mvc) is something you should be looking at. If you are asking me, I will and I have created membership related data objects in my application specific database. You can find the SQL scripts to do so at C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727(v4.0.30319 in case you have VS 2010).

By doing this you can create foreign keys to membership table and achieve your objective.