# Targeting ASPNETDB

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-membership

My asp .net membership ship is targeting "aspnetdb" (some DB which is not visible in my sql server 2008 r2).

I want to make my membership to target some other DB. How can I achieve this??

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121741/how-do-i-setup-a-membership-provider-in-my-existing-database-using-asp-net-mvc/1121774).  Basically, you need to determine if you want to use the existing table structure, or your own.  There is a utility you can use to create the tables for the former.  From there, you just point to the correct database mapped in the configuration file.