# ASP.NET MVC Log in page

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database, security, authentication

I am trying to set up a log in page on my ASP.NET MVC site.  I have a working database that stores all the data needed for my site.  When I started my site, I used the base template in visual studio because I wanted a basic layout so I could get right into displaying the data I needed and then I could go back later and change the styling.  This template created a log in page, which works but I need it to store the tables in my existing database, not a new database.  When I register a user it creates a database on my local db server named "aspnet-KU_PLAN_DEV-20140909071149".  I need it to store these tables in my "KuPlan" database on my local db server.  In my application, my connection string in my web.config file is named "KuPlanEntities" and my model is named "KuPlan.edmx".  I can't figure out why it still creates this new database for the tables needed for authentication/security and would appreciate any tips/help that will help me store them in my current database.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I setup a Membership Provider in my existing database using ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121741/how-do-i-setup-a-membership-provider-in-my-existing-database-using-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Model Folder -> IdentityModel.cs

Change

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
```

To

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("KuPlanEntities", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
```